# PostgreSQL: How to update a identity column to fix the error "duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, identity

I have a table with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar NOT NULL
);
```

When I inserted some records with an explicit *id*:

```sql
INSERT INTO categories (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Children Bicycles'), (2, 'Comfort Bicycles'), (3, 'Cruisers Bicycles');
```

And then tried to insert a new record without specifying an *id*

```sql
INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('Eletric Bicyles');
```

I got the error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "categories_pkey"`

I've already found this question [postgresql duplicate key violates unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448340/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint) where it says that happens due the sequence is outdated and the solution is to set the next value of the sequence to the next `MAX` value of the primary key plus one, but since I declare the primary key as an `IDENTITY` I'm not able to use the answer of that question as a solution for my case.

So, my question is what should I do in order to set the next value of an `IDENTITY` in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the sequence name behind the identity column to modify the value. It can be done with

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER col RESTART WITH 1000;
```